# J48 decision tree in Matlab using Weka for API

Tags: matlab, filter, attributes, weka

I am using Weka for API in Matlab, and I encountered a problem..

I want to add a value in an attribute in my "Test" document:

```
@relation test.txt-weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.NumericToNominal-Rlast

@attribute att_2 numeric
@attribute att_2 numeric
@attribute att_3 {0,1}

@data
```

I want to add '2' this value in att_3 like : `@attribute att_3 {0,1,2}`

And I tried to command :

`test.attribute(2).addStringValue(2)` 
or 
`test.attribute(2).addStringValue('2')`

these two all went wrong .. 
Can anyone help me :(

---

Below is my code
Refer to [How to retrieve class values from WEKA using MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535689/how-to-retrieve-class-values-from-weka-using-matlab)

```
%# Set paths
WEKA_HOME = 'C:\Program Files\Weka-3-8';
javaaddpath([WEKA_HOME '\weka.jar']);
import weka.cores.meta.MatlabLoader.*;

%# load dataset 
load mydata
X = feas;
Y = grp2idx(species);

%# 10-fold crossvalidation
k=10;
cvFolds = crossvalind('Kfold', species, k);   %# get indices of 10-fold CV
cp = classperf(species);   

for i = 1:k  
testIdx = (cvFolds == i); 
trainIdx = ~testIdx;   
xtrain = feas(trainIdx,:);
ytrain = species(trainIdx);
xtest = feas(testIdx,:);
ytest = species(testIdx);

train = [xtrain ytrain];
test =  [xtest ytest];
save train.txt train -ascii
save test.txt test -ascii

fName = 'train.txt';
loader = weka.core.converters.MatlabLoader();
loader.setFile( java.io.File(fName) );
train = loader.getDataSet();
train.setClassIndex( train.numAttributes()-1 );

fName = 'test.txt';
loader = weka.core.converters.MatlabLoader();
loader.setFile( java.io.File(fName) );
test = loader.getDataSet();
test.setClassIndex( test.numAttributes()-1 );

%# convert last attribute (class) from numeric to nominal
filter = weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.NumericToNominal();
filter.setOptions( weka.core.Utils.splitOptions('-R last') );
filter.setInputFormat(train); 
train = filter.useFilter(train, filter);

filter = weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.NumericToNominal();
filter.setOptions( weka.core.Utils.splitOptions('-R last') );
filter.setInputFormat(test);   
test = filter.useFilter(test, filter);

%# train J48 tree
classifier = weka.classifiers.trees.J48();
classifier.setOptions( weka.core.Utils.splitOptions('-O -B -J -A -S -M 1') );
classifier.buildClassifier( train );

%# classify test instances
numInst = test.numInstances();
pred = zeros(numInst,1);
predProbs = zeros(numInst, train.numClasses());

for i=1:numInst
pred(i) = classifier.classifyInstance( test.instance(i-1) );
end

for i=1:numInst
predProbs(i,:) = classifier.distributionForInstance( test.instance(i-1) );
end

eval = weka.classifiers.Evaluation(train);
eval.evaluateModel(classifier, test, javaArray('java.lang.Object',1));

disp( char(eval.toSummaryString()) )

end
```

My Data set contains 31 datas , each data has two attributes and one class.

The class of my dataset contains three values : '0' or '1' or '2'. Only 4 datas are in class '2' , other 27 datas are in class '0' or '1'.

When I'm using 10 fold cross-validation , only few folds (about 4 folds) won't get wrong when I run the code.

But the rest (6 folds) will all show error messages:
"Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch."
while running

```
for i=1:numInst
predProbs(i,:) = classifier.distributionForInstance( test.instance(i-1) );
end
```

First I don't know why , and then I found those 6 folds don't contain data which is in class '2' in their "Test data". They only have datas in class '0' or '1' in their "Test data" and have datas in class '0','1','2' in their "Train data".

And the folds which can run successfully contains data in class '2' in their "Test Data".

---

Those which doesn't contain class '2' in their "Test" shows

```
@relation test.txt-weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.NumericToNominal-Rlast

@attribute att_1 numeric
@attribute att_2 numeric
@attribute att_3 {0,1}

@data
864.86315,40.15,0
1396.0296,36.263158,0
249.6065,71.5,1
```

So, I'm wondering if I should add '2' in @attribute att_3 {0,1} to solve the problem.. Or the problem is not this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to apply `weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.AddValues` with options `-C last -L 0,1,2` to your test data, after converting the class attribute to nominal but before attempting to use the test data for prediction. This will ensure that the class attribute in the test data matches the one in the training data even if the test dataset doesn't contain any instances with a given class value.

I assume there is a reason that you want to do the partitioning for cross-validation in MATLAB before building the models in Weka though, rather than just letting Weka build a cross-validated model?

Comment: Okay,I'll try it tmr when I went to lab. Umm, the reason I do cross-validation in Matlab for training data and test data is that I think if I run 10 fold , the datas in folds should be different every time, and the average of 10 fold's predict accuracy will be a little different . And I've used Weka to build a cross-validation model , and I got totally the same result every time. Quite weird.

Comment: @Claire Weka normally initialises the random number generator with a default value each time you run it - this can be convenient for verifying that your code is still doing the same thing after a change, for example. To use a different set of cross-validation partitions for each model building runs, try calling the classifier's `setRandomSeed` method with a different value each time.

Comment: OMG!!!!!!!!!!!!! It works!!! Thank you so much:) ; and I found this page https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/50120-using-weka-in-matlab?focused=3889451&tab=function with setRandomSeed . I'll try it next time!

Answer (score 0):

It requires a few more steps. Please find my example below:

```
%nAttributes is number of Attributes
YourAttributeName = 'MyFavoriteAttributeName';
YourAttributeValue = 123.456;

fvWekaAttribute=javaObject('weka.core.FastVector');
fvWekaAttribute.addElement(Attribute(YourAttributeName));
DataSet=javaObject('weka.core.Instances','Rel',fvWekaAttribute,10);
DataSet.setClassIndex(nAttributes-1);
iExample=javaObject('weka.core.DenseInstance',nAttributes);
iExample.setValue(fvWekaAttribute.elementAt(0),YourAttributeValue);
DataSet.add(iExample);
```

or if the attribute is a nominal Attribute

```
%nAttributes is number of Attributes
YourAttributeName = 'MyFavoriteAttributeName';
YourAttributeValue = 123.456;

nominalEgotypeFastVector=javaObject('weka.core.FastVector');
nominalEgotypeFastVector.addElement('YourType1');
nominalEgotypeFastVector.addElement('YourType2');
nominalEgotypeFastVector.addElement('SomeMoreType');
fvWekaAttribute.addElement(Attribute(YourAttributeName,nominalEgotypeFastVector));
DataSet=javaObject('weka.core.Instances','Rel',fvWekaAttribute,10);
DataSet.setClassIndex(nAttributes-1);
iExample=javaObject('weka.core.DenseInstance',nAttributes);
iExample.setValue(fvWekaAttribute.elementAt(0),YourAttributeValue);
DataSet.add(iExample); % continue with DataSet
```

Comment: was this helpful?

Comment: I don't really understand your above code.. umm just don't know which part I need to substitute ..:(

Comment: Please update your question with further details about what errors you get.

Comment: Okay, I think I shoud tell you my problem more detail. I am doing my homework to classify 31 datas and using j48 decision tree. And I have to use Weka for API in Matlab . I've refered to "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535689/how-to-retrieve-class-values-from-weka-using-matlab" this page. I'll add my code in my question later.

Comment: YourAttributeName = 'att_3';  YourAttributeValue =2;  fvWekaAttribute=javaObject('weka.core.FastVector'); fvWekaAttribute.addElement(Attribute(YourAttributeName)); Is that what you mean ? Command like this ? I got "Undefined function 'Attribute' for input arguments of type 'char'." .